# All "preselected" radio buttons become unchecked when I make first selection

Tags: jquery, radio-button

So I'm attempting to create a script that selects all "Yes" radio buttons. I am able to get this to work properly using the following code:

```
  $("input[value='on']:even").prop('checked', 'checked');
```

For some reason if the user decides to change one answer to N all other radio buttons become checked.

Also if i don't actually click every radio button then it doesn't pass validation.

Comment: can you please explain it more clearer, I am not able able to understand your use cases.

Comment: `prop('checked', true);` will change value.